# Why is a negative integer not a valid pattern in a macro?

Tags: macros, rust, pattern-matching

Let us consider a simple enum implementation with a static method that check whether a value has an associated value (the efficiency of the implementation is not to be regarded here):

```
enum Letter {
    Alpha = -1,
    A = 0,
    B = 1,
    C = 2,
}

impl Letter {
    pub fn in_enum(value: isize) -> bool
    {
        match value {
            -1 => true,
            0 => true,
            1 => true,
            2 => true,
            _ => false,
        }
    }
}
```

Now, let us write a macro for building enums with an equivalent `in_enum` method. The macro below was written with some guidance from the Serde guide for [enum deserialization as numbers](https://serde.rs/enum-number.html), in which matching for enum variant values also occurs.

```
macro_rules! my_enum {
    ($name:ident { $($variant:ident = $value:expr, )* }) => {
        #[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug, Eq, PartialEq)]
        pub enum $name {
            $($variant = $value,)*
        }

        impl $name {
            pub fn in_enum(value: isize) -> bool
            {
                match value {
                    $( $value => true, )*
                    _ => false,
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

my_enum!(Letter {
  Alpha = -1,
  A = 0,
  B = 1,
  C = 2,
});
```

[Playground](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=cb85a3b7fed47c7f71b790d813c039d8&version=1.18.0).
With version 1.18.0, the compiler won't accept the variant with a negative integer.

```
error: expected pattern, found `-1`
  --> src/main.rs:13:24
   |
13 |                     $( $value => true, )*
   |                        ^^^^^^
```

This seems to happen regardless of how I write this pattern down in the macro, or whether I use `i32` or `isize` for the `value` method parameter. Changing the fragment specifier of `$value` to `pat` is also out of the question: the compiler will refuse to build the enum, even without negative variant values.

```
error: expected expression, found `-1`
 --> src/main.rs:5:26
  |
5 |             $($variant = $value,)*
  |                          ^^^^^^
```

What's surprising about this is that it works without using macros, as well as when I discard the `Alpha` variant.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Because you matched an `expr`, not a `pat`.  Expressions and patterns are two totally different parts of the language.

Comment: @DK Indeed they are. But that alone doesn't explain why `0` is accepted as a pattern while `-1` isn't. The part where `-1` is composed of the `-` token followed by the literal could be the culprit here.

Comment: Huh.  I'm surprised that it does accept `0`.  I suspect it's because `-1` is (if I remember correctly) internally represented as `Neg::neg(1)` rather than a literal negative integer, and that might be tripping up whatever part of the code is trying to convert the `expr` AST into a pattern.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [a bug in the compiler](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/42820) and is already [fixed in the nightly version](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/42886) as of today (Jul 5, 2017), and released in stable version 1.20.0.